# Deploy QT plugin with its own DLL depences

Tags: qt, plugins, deployment

I have a QT application `app.exe` and a QT plugin `plugin.dll`. My `plugin.dll` depends on many other dynamic libraries (e.g. `lib1.dll`, `lib2.dll` and so on). To distribute my project I have this folder structure (ignoring QT libraries):

```
app.exe
plugins\
    plugin.dll
lib1.dll
lib2.dll
lib3.dll
```

The problem is that there are too many dependences on `libX.dll` and I want to hide them in a plugin folder, e.g.:

```
app.exe
plugin\
    plugin.dll
    lib1.dll
    lib2.dll
    lib3.dll
```

But this way libraries `libX.dll` are "unseen" to my plugin, so that it cannot be loaded. Is there any way to solve this problem?

I am using this code to import `libX.dll` in `plugin.dll`'s `pro`-file:

```
LIBS += -Lpath -l lib1 -l lib2 -l lib3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways of solving this problem is:

1. Link all libraries dynamically (at runtime)
2. Add extra location to search for the libraries

These changes should be done in `plugin.dll` code:

```
/* Declare a pointer to import function */

typedef void (*FUNCTION)();
FUNCTION f;

/* Make system search the DLLs in my plugin folder */

// Variable "app" contains directory of the application, not the plugin
QDir app = QDir(qApp->applicationDirPath());
// Combine path
QString plugin_path = app.filePath("plugins/");
// Adding full path for DLL search
SetDllDirectory(plugin_path.toStdWString().c_str());

/* Linking the library */

QLibrary mylib("mylib.dll");
f = (FUNCTION ) mylib.resolve("function");
if (f != NULL)
    f(); // You got the function from DLL
else
    return; // DLL could not be loaded
```

This solution has disadvanges:

- It is not platform independent (I think you can avoid using `SetDllDirectory` in UNIX-like systems but I am not sure)
- If you import a lot of functions you will have a lot of pointers

Does any one know pure Qt solution?